Python program to send updates to a vendor's API works accept for processing the return response
This is my first attempt at using an API. I went with Python and everything seemed to work -- I was able to send 17,500+ records to a vendor and they are showing up perfect on their website. The problem is that the vendor is using different IDs then we are. I work for a public school system and this is for our bus transportation. I pass the vendor bus stops and in their response they pass me the ID that was created. I then have to take that ID and pass it into a SQL Server procedure to update a cross reference table. I tested this by just sending a single record and it worked great, so I turned on the process to push all 17,500+. When I checked the cross reference table, I'm seeing unexpected results.  Of the 17,500 records, only 13 got updated with the Vendor ID. On top of that, there is a status field that should have gotten updated from "New" to "Processed", and it didn't get updated even in the 13 records that got the Vendor ID updated.
I don't know what I did wrong, but I'm hoping somebody can spot the issue.  Here is my python code:
import pyodbc as db 
import requests

url = "<vendor URL>"

def GetData():
    connVendorData = db.connect(<Driver Info>)
    connVendorData.setdecoding(db.SQL_CHAR, encoding='latin1')
    connVendorData.setencoding('latin1')
    
    cursor_Vendor = connVendorData.cursor()
    cursor_Vendor.execute('''exec get_addressBookUpdates''')

    for row in cursor_Vendor: 
        payload = {
            "geofence": { "circle": {
                    "latitude": str(row.latitude),
                    "longitude": str(row.longitude),
                    "radiusMeters": str(row.radius)
                } },
            "formattedAddress": row.formattedAddress,
            "longitude": str(row.longitude),
            "latitude": str(row.latitude),
            "name": row.addressBookTitle
        }
        headers = {
            "accept": "application/json",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "authorization": "<vendor token>"
        }

        response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

        connMyCompanyData = db.connect(<Driver Info>)
        connMyCompanyData.setdecoding(db.SQL_CHAR, encoding='latin1')
        connMyCompanyData.setencoding('latin1')

        cursor_MyCompany = connMyCompanyData.cursor()
        cursor_MyCompany.execute('''exec update_stopIDs_xref_AfterProcessing ?, ?''', row.status, response.text)
        
GetData()

And here is the stored procedure that is updating the cross reference table:
alter PROC update_stopIDs_xref_AfterProcessing
@status VARCHAR(25),
@json NVARCHAR(MAX)

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON 

--Test Parms
--DECLARE @json nvarchar(MAX)
--DECLARE @status VARCHAR(25) = 'New'

--SET @json = '{
--  "data": {
--    "id": "137279769",
--    "name": "MILLGATE RD @ LA GRANGE RD",
--    "createdAtTime": "2024-05-12T15:12:47.880383692Z",
--    "formattedAddress": "MILLGATE RD @ LA GRANGE RD",
--    "geofence": {
--      "circle": {
--        "latitude": 38.27088968,
--        "longitude": -85.57484079,
--        "radiusMeters": 25
--      }
--    },
--    "latitude": 38.27088968,
--    "longitude": -85.57484079
--  }
--}'

--Load the parms into a #temp table 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp 
SELECT  JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.data.id')                  vendorID,
        JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.data.formattedAddress')    formattedAddress,
        JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.data.createdAtTime')       createdTime
INTO    #temp 

--Update stopIDs_xref depending on the processing that happened 
IF @status = 'New'
    UPDATE  stopIDs_xref
    SET     vendorId = t.vendorID,
            status = 'Processed'
    FROM    stopIDs_xref sx
            JOIN #temp t ON t.formattedAddress = sx.formattedAddress 
ELSE IF @status = 'Update'
    UPDATE  stopIDs_xref 
    SET     status = 'Processed'
    FROM    stopIDs_xref sx
            JOIN #temp t ON t.formattedAddress = sx.formattedAddress
ELSE IF @status = 'Delete'
    DELETE 
    FROM    stopIDs_xref 
    FROM    stopIDs_xref sx
            JOIN #temp t ON t.formattedAddress = sx.formattedAddress 


After more researching I discovered the issue was some basic logic flaws in my code. 1) My connection string pointing back to my SQL Server was in the for loop, so I was essentially creating a new connection with each iteration which I guess was overwhelming the database. I moved the connection string outside of the for loop. 2) doing this, I could follow along as the updates were occurring and everything looked good, but for some reason when the processing was finished the updates would "disappear" and the data was being revered back to it's original values. Discovered I needed to add a Commit in the logic.  3) Moved the connection close string to the end of the logic.  After that everything worked just as anticipated.  Hope this helps others who may have the same issue.
import pyodbc as db 
import requests

url_insert = "https://api.samsara.com/addresses"
connSamsaraData = db.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
            'Server=appdb.jefferson.kyschools.us,7771;'
            'Database=Transportation_Samsara;'
            'UID:jcps_reports;'
            'PWD=Gl4sRsr3p0rt5'
            'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor_Samsara = connSamsaraData.cursor()

connJCPSData = db.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
            'Server=appdb.jefferson.kyschools.us,7771;'
            'Database=Transportation_Samsara;'
            'UID:jcps_reports;'
            'PWD=Gl4sRsr3p0rt5'
            'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor_JCPS = connJCPSData.cursor()

def InsertNewAddresses():
    cursor_Samsara.execute('''exec get_addressBookInserts''')

    for row in cursor_Samsara: 
    payload = {
        "geofence": { "circle": {
            "latitude": str(row.latitude),
            "longitude": str(row.longitude),
            "radiusMeters": str(row.radius)
        } },
        "formattedAddress": row.formattedAddress,
        "longitude": str(row.longitude),
        "latitude": str(row.latitude),
        "name": row.addressBookTitle
    }
    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "authorization": "Bearer samsara_api_cDRDqPgdOJsnnOBPkAKXAicynXPA8L"
    }

    response = requests.post(url_insert, json=payload, headers=headers)

    cursor_JCPS.execute('''exec update_stopIDs_xref_AfterProcessing ?, ?''', row.status, response.text)

    cursor_JCPS.commit()

def UpdateExistingAddresses():
    cursor_Samsara.execute('''exec get_addressBookUpdates''')

    for row in cursor_Samsara: 
    url_update = "https://api.samsara.com/addresses/" + str(row.samsaraId)

    payload = {
        "geofence": { "circle": {
            "latitude": str(row.latitude),
            "longitude": str(row.longitude),
            "radiusMeters": str(row.radius)
        } },
        "formattedAddress": row.formattedAddress,
        "latitude": str(row.latitude),
        "longitude": str(row.longitude),
        "name": row.addressBookTitle
    }
    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "authorization": "Bearer samsara_api_cDRDqPgdOJsnnOBPkAKXAicynXPA8L"
    }

    response = requests.patch(url_update, json=payload, headers=headers)

    print(response.text)

    cursor_JCPS.execute('''exec update_stopIDs_xref_AfterProcessing ?, ?''', row.status, response.text)

    cursor_JCPS.commit()

def DeleteOldAddresses():
    cursor_Samsara.execute('''exec get_addressBookDeletes''')

    for row in cursor_Samsara: 
    url_delete = "https://api.samsara.com/addresses/" + str(row.samsaraId)

    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "authorization": "Bearer samsara_api_cDRDqPgdOJsnnOBPkAKXAicynXPA8L"
    }

    response = requests.delete(url_delete, headers=headers)

    cursor_JCPS.execute('''exec update_stopIDs_xref_AfterProcessing ?, ?''', row.status, response.text)

    cursor_JCPS.commit()

InsertNewAddresses()
UpdateExistingAddresses()
DeleteOldAddresses()

connSamsaraData.close()
connJCPSData.close()

